# What is the easiest way to achieve a 200k minimum score in the Hollowed Lair Nightfall activity?

Tags: destiny-2

Just looking for an easy way to get a 200k minimum score in the Hollowed Lair Nightfall.  I have read the drop chance of NF exclusive loot is dependent on the highest score achieved in that NF.     Unfortunately, I haven't played much NF to know what Five of Cards modifiers to use, as well as what gear to bring to make the fight a lot less tough, especially if I am trying to solo.

Comment: I don't think drops are linked to score. I got my Braytech Osprey by speed running the strike in a team with Arc Singe, Heavyweight and Wardcliff Coil. Took us a few runs, but we got it in the end.

Comment: Getting 200k, I'd think you'd want a level handicap, match game, extinguish etc. Something to get a 3x or more bonus. Probably take Hard Light or Borealis to adapt to different shield elements. Seems doable though https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VU__9ZCHD8

Comment: @DavidYell No, it's been confirmed that there are 3 tiers of drop rates -- no score, 100k, and 200k. Each tier will increase the chance of you getting that Nightfall's specific loot. This is why people want 200k, so they can farm Mindbender's Ambition.

Comment: Must have got mine before the changes I guess!

Comment: @DavidYell I'm not saying you won't drop Mindbender's at a lower tier, but your drop chance per run is increased. I was getting about 1 mindbenders in 5 runs without a high score tier, which dropped it to 1 in 4 after hitting 100k. Just struggling to hit 200k without getting instantly obliterated by a trash mob.

Comment: @senpai there is no way the drop rate is 1 in 5 at 100k. I ran Strange Terrain over 60 times at 100k score before i got it to drop. The key is to have the emblem that drops for a 100k score on the strike equipped. The drop rate is greatly increased if you have the emblem equipped. Also 200k solo is impossible.

Comment: @Colin Did you see the link David provided above? That is literally a 200k solo score.   I have seen 200k solo scores of Hollowed Lair on YT, but those are definitely not easy at all.

Comment: The video links to a 200k score on Will of a Thousand not Hollowed Lair but I do stand corrected, it is not impossible, just extremely difficult. My reasearch when trying for Braytech Ospray is that the emblem with a 100k bonus for the week active increases the drop rate massively. That seems far more achieveble to me.